# Why can't I seem to merge a normal Object into a Mongo Document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js, lodash

I have a data feed from a 3rd party server that I am pulling in and converting to JSON.  The data feed will never have my mongoDB's auto-generated `_id`s in it, but there is a unique identifier called `vehicle_id`.

The function below is what is handling taking the data-feed generated json object `fresh_event_obj` and copying its values into a mongo document if there is a mongo document with the same `vehicle_id`.

```
function update_vehicle(fresh_event_obj) {
    console.log("Updating Vehicle " + fresh_event_obj.vehicleID + "...");

    Vehicle.find({ vehicleID: fresh_event_obj.vehicleID }, function (err, event_obj) {
      if (err) {
        handle_error(err);
      } else {
        var updated = _.merge(event_obj[0], fresh_event_obj);

        updated.save(function (err) {
          if (err) {
            handle_error(err)
          } else {
            console.log("Vehicle Updated");
          }
        });

      }
    });
  }
```

The structures of `event_obj[0]` and  `fresh_event_obj` are identical, except that `event_obj[0]` has `_id` and `__v` while the "normal" object doesn't.

When I run _.merge on these two, or even my own recursive function that just copies values from the latter to the former, nothing in the `updated` object is different from the `event_obj[0]`, despite `fresh_event_obj` having all new values.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I feel it is obvious and I'm just failing to see it.

Comment: Does your schema has entries for whatever properties `fresh_event_obj` is trying to insert?

Comment: You seem to be using loadash, in which case [checkout this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448343/lodash-merge-with-mongoose). Try changing `_.merge` to `_.extend`

Comment: @laggingreflex I tried ._extend to no avail. I have the same issue. Nothing changes in the `updated` object.  My schema does not have any entries yet, currently `strict` is set to false.  However, even if that is a problem, my issue is that `_.merge` or even recursively just setting the object values equal to one another does not seem to be working.  I do `JSON.stringify` of the 3 objects involved and that shows the problem exists before I even get to `.save`, the objects simply aren't merging their values.

Comment: Ah, there's the problem. *You would think* that setting `{strict:false}` ought to make setting new properties work but unfortunately it doesn't ([open issue on GH](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/2439#issuecomment-96923180)), not for new properties at least. So try defining them in your schema

Comment: It is a LOT of properties, so I'll have to get to it in the morning. I will report back, if it works you should make an answer so I can close the question.

Comment: Or, you can use `doc.set('prop', value)` syntax which actually does work. You can use for-in loop to go through object properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you don't have properties defined in your schema, and if they don't already exist, you can't create them with

```
doc.prop = value
```

even if you have `{strict:false}` in your schema.

The only way to set new properties is to do

```
doc.set('prop', value)
```

(You still have to have `{strict:false}` in your schema if that property doesn't exist in your schema)

As for having too many properties to be defined in schema, you can always use for-in loop to go through object properties

```
for(key in fresh_event_obj)
    event_obj.set(key, fresh_event_obj[key]);
```

Comment: This worked for me, sorry for the slow response.  Thanks for helping me out.